# Using a user's .bashrc in a systemd service

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am using systemd service for my script
I need to set environment vaules from a home/user/.bashrc

`source /home/user/.bashrc` not works in script and systemd seed don't support sourcing function.
Help me

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a `.bashrc` rather than an EnvironmentFile?

Comment: I use commands that works on user terminal

Comment: when i use command they said me cannot find path

Comment: and some variables that i exported in bashrc need to my command

Comment: so i made this question. why you made down my question? What is fault?

Comment: Please check [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: [Running a bash script from systemd as if I logged in](https://serverfault.com/q/805644/145545), [Getting a systemd unit to read your .bashrc file for its environment](http://tech.akom.net/archives/93-Getting-a-systemd-unit-to-read-your-.bashrc-file-for-its-environment.html), [Execute a program at login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117237/56041), [How do I make my systemd service run via specific user and start on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/q/676007), etc.

Comment: @jww, if the closer matches among those were StackOverflow questions, I'd be glad to mark this duplicate. However, that's not the case. (It's also notable that at least one of them gives the same bug-prone advice that riguang is following; that faulty advice is floating around is, IMHO, one of the compelling reasons to counter it with more cautiously-constructed answers).

Answer (score 31):

### If you must...

Instead of trying to generate an EnvironmentFile, have a shell execute your startup scripts and *then* execute your command. This avoids steps that can introduce a mismatch (as between how `env` stores your environment, and how the systemd `EnvironmentFile` option loads it).

---

#### To source your target user's startup scripts:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=/bin/bash -l -c 'exec "$@"' _ your-command arg1 arg2 ...
```

---

#### To source an arbitrary file:

Here, instead of using `bash -l` to run a login shell, we explicitly source `$0`, and pass `/home/user/.bashrc` in that position.

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=user
Group=user
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '. "$0" && exec "$@"' /home/user/.bashrc your-command arg1 arg2 ...
```

---

### But Don't. Really.

- `.bashrc` files are generally intended for setting up interactive environments. This means that their settings are often not appropriate for services.
- Building a separate `EnvironmentFile` that you hand-audit for your service means you know *exactly* what the service is running with, and can configure it separately from the interactive environment. *If* you've hand-audited that EnvironmentFile to have the same meaning when executed by a shell, you could also run `set -a; source /path/to/your-environment-file; set +a` in your `.bashrc` to pull its environment variables in.
- From a security perspective, it's generally unwise to let a service modify any executable code it runs -- providing such permissions means that an attacker who has breached a service can make their breach persistent even without any secondary privilege escalation attacks. Using an `EnvironmentFile` in a non-user-writable location like `/etc/conf.d` is thus safer than a dotfile under that user's home directory.

Comment: oh it seems much simple, Let me check if it works ;) Thank you @Charles

Comment: okay Charles, You seems much good than I, I will try yours advise

Comment: If the script is meant to run dependent of the user's shell environment then calling it with `bash -l` is right and using a static EnvironmentFile file is wrong. There are variables that can be dynamically initialized by Bash's initialization scripts. Obviously you might suggest moving these dynamic initializations to systemd but that isn't always adaptable and practical.

Comment: I needed to put the entire bash command into quotation marks:
`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '. "$0" && exec "$@" /home/user/.bashrc your-command arg1 arg2 ...'
`

Comment: @Philipp Doing that defeats the purpose of using `"$@"`. In particular, when you do that, you don't have a `$0` _or_ a `$@` because everything goes into the `-c` argument to be run as a script. Indeed, I'm surprised it works at all -- I would have expected the `. "$0"` to fail (on account of `$0` not being set to the name of a `source`able script), and consequently everything else to not be run at all.

Comment: @Philipp, ...if you can't get the answer to work _exactly as originally given_, could you please open a new question showing the problem you encountered, and `@`-notify me in?